# Is there an ultimate question which would give the answer to distinghuish whether you are talking to a robot or not?

Tags: ethics

Robots can become very intelligent. So suppose in future they are there and looks and behave a bit like humans. What question could be asked by which you can decide whether it is a robot or not?

Comment: Passing or failing the Turing test is a comment upon the agent conducting the test, not the agent taking the test. In short, no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculation only.

Comment: You need to tighten up the question. There is no question guaranteed to tell you whether you are talking to a robot simply because a robot could be programmed to respond to any question with "my lawyer has advised me not to answer that question." Or indeed not to respond to it at all. For that matter, the robot could tell lies: after all, people do. If the question is, "is there something a human could say that a robot could not under any circumstances?" then no.

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires making certain assumptions. First, we assume that the robot makes use of a computational machine to "think". Second, we assume that these machines are never truly able to achieve the same level of intelligence as humans, no matter how close they get. ([Basically, human thought is necessarily non-computable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction#Penrose.E2.80.93Lucas_argument)) The latter assumption is highly disputed.

Assuming the above, one could ask the robot certain questions "to which it will either give a wrong answer, or fail to give an answer at all however much time is allowed for a reply." (Turing 1950:444) If it gives the wrong answer, you *could* distinguish it from a human, given that you ascribe to the above assumptions. The latter possibility complicates things since you might end up waiting for an infinite amount of time. So, these types of questions *could* give you the ability to distinguish whether you are talking to a machine or a human, but it's not necessarily the case that they *will*.

I'll add some more detail about these types of questions. In brief, there are some mathematical results which show that within certain formal systems, there exists a class of expressible but not provable statements within that system. In other words, using the constraints of the system, you can formulate some expression which cannot be proven in that same system.

[This paper by Manfred Kerber](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mmk/papers/05-KI.html) mentions:

> Since Gödel proved that in each sound formal system - which is strong
>   enough to formulate arithmetic - there exists a formula which cannot
>   be proved by the system (assumed the system is consistent), and since
>   we (human beings) can see that such a formula must be true, human and
>   machine reasoning must inevitably be different in nature, even in the
>   restricted area of mathematical logic. This attributes to human
>   mathematical reasoning a very particular role, which seems to go
>   beyond rational thought. Note that it is not about general human
>   behaviour, and not even about the process of how to find mathematical
>   proofs (which is still only little understood), but just about the
>   checking of (finite) mathematical arguments.

You can also see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing-test/#MatObj for more about this.

Again, this argument rests on the idea that human thought is necessarily non-computable.

Answer (score -3):

You might just ask "are you a robot". If the answer is yes, you can safely treat it as a robot. If the answer is no, treat it as a human. In both cases, be aware that you might be wrong.